# vb.net datetime.parseExact error message saying invalid format

Tags: vb.net

Hi am trying to use the datetime.parse exact object in vb.net, but I keep getting an error saying invalid format.  Here is my statement, could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong??

```
       Dim TimeStart As Date

       TimeStart = DateTime.ParseExact("2013.07.15-07:10:02", "yyyy.MM.dd-HH:MM:SS", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat)
```

Comment: You know you're asking for the Month twice in that format, right?

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the seconds must be lower case. Also, you're asking for the month twice. I suspect this is the format string you need:

> yyyy.MM.dd-HH:mm:ss

Just as an informational bit, the upper case 'H' means it's looking for 24-hour time, instead of 12-hour time. Lower-case 'h' would mean 12-hour time. Here is the reference for custom datetime format string rules:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx